# MSAccess Gets Warning Message Since Client Locked Down Users Machine

Tags: ms-access, configuration, system

I have a client that runs an MSAccess application.  Since they locked down the users machines, when the user opens the application they receive this message "You do not have access to make the required system configuration modifications.  Please rerun this installation from an administrator".  It lets them continue but the users get confused with the message.  Would this simply be a registery setting being accessed?  If so which one?

Thanks

Don

Comment: What Access version? What Windows version?

Answer (score 1):

If the machine is really locked down, then it's possible that the location of the MS Access database is in a directory where they do not have file create permissions.  This then prevents Access from creating the necessary record-locking file upon start-up.

If this is your case, you may research to see if you can move the Access database to a different location to where the user has appropriate read/write access.